# Show specific post ID - Query posts / Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, categories, posts

I've got this command to show the sub posts from that category but I want to be able to just show 1 post by ID but still under the specific category.

Here's the code I have:

```
<?php query_posts( array('cat' => $category_id,'posts_per_page'=>'1')); ?>
<li>
<?php  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="sponsor-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ) ?></div>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure on what you want.

If you want to show a single post and you have the id of that post, just add `'p' => 123` to the `query_posts` array.

```
<?php query_posts( array('cat' => $category_id,'posts_per_page'=>'1', 'p' => 123)); ?>
```

Replace `123` with the id of the post you want to retrieve.

Comment: This works correctly,thank you but the code doesn't work the way I was hoping. Basically, I only wanted this post to show when I was on the parent category, and hide when on a category that it isn't a child of.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd have a look at this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters If you look at the 'Show Child Posts/Pages' section it gives you an idea on what needs to be done. Unfortunately I have never used those methods, so I'm not sure how to give you an explanation really. Sorry.